# Display the correct colors of a logo in a icon in compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have the following composable

```
@Composable
fun GoogleLoginButton(onLoginClicked: () -> Unit) {
    IconButton(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(color = Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)),
        onClick = {
            onLoginClicked()
        },
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            Icon(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 12.dp).align(Alignment.CenterStart),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_google_logo),
                contentDescription = "Google logo"
            )
            Text(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontSize = 18.sp,
                text = "Google", color = Color.Black)
        }
    }
}
```

It displays the correct logo for for some reason its displayed as black icon.
[image]

However, the actual colors of the vector image is this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Icon` has a `tint` argument which is set to `LocalContentColor` by default. Either set it to `Color.Unspecified`, or use `Image` composable instead.